# El método render de Livewire no se llama al actualizar un wire.model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

¡Hola, compañeros!

espero tengan un buen día.

estoy teniendo un problema, y no sé cómo solucionarlo. El problema es con Laravel y livewire, pues por alguna razon no entra al método render.

Este es el código.

Aqui es donde se manda a llamar a la vista de livewire.

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            <i class="fi fi-rr-users mr-2"></i>
            {{ __('Usuarios') }}
        </h2>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn-uicons.flaticon.com/uicons-bold-rounded/css/uicons-bold-rounded.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn-uicons.flaticon.com/uicons-regular-rounded/css/uicons-regular-rounded.css'>
    </x-slot>

    @livewire('paciente');

</x-app-layout>
```

La vista en livewire la tengo así.

```
<div class="container my-12">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">

            <div class="w-1/6 mx-5">
                <x-input-label for="Buscar" :value="__('Buscar')" />
                <x-text-input id="Buscar" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="Text" placeholder="buscar usuario"
                    wire:model="search" />
            </div>

            <div class="py-12 mx-3 overflow-auto text-center">
                <table class="my-5 w-full border-collapse bg-white shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg table-auto justify-center">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="py-2 px-4 border-b">ID</th>
                            <th class="py-2 px-4 border-b">Nombre de usuario</th>
                            <th class="py-2 px-4 border-b">Celular</th>
                            <th class="py-2 px-4 border-b">Fecha de ingreso</th>
                            <th class="py-2 px-4 border-b">Fecha de alta</th>
                            <th class="py-2 px-4 border-b">N/Familiar</th>
                            <th class="py-2 px-4 border-b"></th>
                            <th class="py-2 px-4 border-b"></th>
                            <th class="py-2 px-4 border-b"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($pacientes as $pac)
                            <tr class="">
                                <td class="py-2 px-4 border-b">{{ $pac->id }}</td>
                                <td class="py-2 px-4 border-b">{{ $pac->Nombre }}</td>
                                <td class="py-2 px-4 border-b">{{ $pac->NumeroDC }}</td>
                                <td class="py-2 px-4 border-b">{{ $pac->Fecha }}</td>
                                <td class="py-2 px-4 border-b">{{ $pac->Estado }}</td>
                                <td class="py-2 px-4 border-b">{{ $pac->Familiar }}</td>
                                <td class="py-2 border-b">
                                    <x-primary-button class="bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800">
                                        <i class="fi fi-rr-interrogation mr-2"></i>
                                        {{ _('Ver') }}
                                    </x-primary-button>
                                </td>
                                <td class="py-2 border-b">
                                    <x-a-button href="{{ url('usuarios/' . $pac->id . '/edit') }}"
                                        class="bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-600">
                                        <i class="fi fi-rr-edit"></i>
                                        {{ _('Modificar') }}
                                    </x-a-button>
                                </td>
                                <td class="py-2 border-b">
                                    <form action="" method="POST">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('DELETE')
                                        <x-a-button href="{{ url('usuarios') }}" class="bg-red-700 hover:bg-red-800">
                                            <i class="fi fi-br-cross mr-2"></i>
                                            {{ _('Eliminar') }}
                                        </x-a-button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Así esta el input para buscar.

```
<div class="w-1/6 mx-5">
                <x-input-label for="Buscar" :value="__('Buscar')" />
                <x-text-input id="Buscar" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="Text" placeholder="buscar usuario"
                    wire:model="search" />
            </div>
```

y asi el metodo render.

```
class Paciente extends Component
{
    public $search = '';
    public function render()
    {
        $pacientes = Pacientes::where('Nombre', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')->get();
        return view('livewire.paciente', ['pacientes' => $pacientes]);
    }

}
```

Cuando escribo en la caja de texto se supone oh pensaría que debería entrar al método render, pero por alguna razon no entra al método. no tengo ningún error en consola.

ustedes que tienen más experiencia, ¿me pueden ayudar, por favor?

de antemano y adelantandome, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema es el siguiente.

Revisando las versiones encontré que se esta usando livewire en su version 3

por lo que ya no basta solamente con poner

```
wire:model
```

ahora se tiene que usar

```
wire:model.live
```

para que renderice el componente, pues sin este la vista no se actualiza, solo se actualiza por ejemplo en los botones.